# How to deal with 0,0 marker error in Google Map Direction API?

Tags: android, api, google-maps, kotlin, marker

I try to do an android application and I'm trying to use Google map Direction API to draw line between 2 marker and when I try to decode the polyline point in the JSON I have from goole server I have a bunch of marker set near to the position 0.0,0.0 like in my screenshoot bellow

my polyline decode function is

```
private fun decodePoly(polylineArrayList: ArrayList<String>): List<LatLng> {
    val poly = ArrayList<LatLng>()
    var index = 0
    for (i in 0 until polylineArrayList.size-1) {
        val encoded = polylineArrayList[i]
        val len = encoded.length
        var lat = 0
        var lng = 0

        while (index < len -1) {
            var b: Int
            var shift = 0
            var result = 0
            do {
                b = encoded[index++].toInt() - 63
                result = result or (b and 0x1f shl shift)
                shift += 5
            } while (b >= 0x20 )
            val dlat = if (result and 1 != 0) (result shr 1).inv() else result shr 1
            lat += dlat

            shift = 0
            result = 0
            do {
                b = encoded[index++].toInt() - 63
                result = result or (b and 0x1f shl shift)
                shift += 5
            } while (b >= 0x20 )
            val dlng = if (result and 1 != 0) (result shr 1).inv() else result shr 1
            lng += dlng

            val p = LatLng(lat.toDouble() / 1E5,
                    lng.toDouble() / 1E5)
            poly.add(p)
        }
    }
    return poly
}
```

here is the code where i draw the line (i do in in the on success from my asynck task

```
private val options = PolylineOptions()
private val latLongB = LatLngBounds.Builder()
override fun onSuccess(googleDirectionData: GoogleDirectionData?) {
     val polylineArrayList = ArrayList<String>()
     for (route in googleDirectionData?.routes!!) {
          for (leg in route.legs) {
              for (step in leg.steps)
                  polylineArrayList.add(step.polyline.points)
          }
      }
      val polypts = decodePoly(polylineArrayList)
      for (point in polypts) {
          options.add(point)
          latLongB.include(point)
      }
val caisseMarker = LatLng(caisse.wsg84[0], caisse.wsg84[1])
options.add(caisseMarker)
latLongB.include(caisseMarker)
val bounds = latLongB.build()
// add polyline to the map
map.addPolyline(options)
// show map with route centered
map.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngBounds(bounds, 100))
}
```

[bunch of marker near 0.0,0.0](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BxXm2.png)

did someone know how to fix this in order 
to no longer have a marker to position 0.0,0.0?

Comment: Please add your code where your are drawing to the map

Comment: You can add that image directly in your post which would make reading your post a bit more efficient

Comment: yes i will update my post

Comment: R.F.Nelson I'm not allowed to do this...  I don't know why

Answer (score 0):

If you want boost your performance, you should use pre built libraries.

Have a look at

https://github.com/jd-alexander/Google-Directions-Android

https://github.com/bkhezry/MapDrawingTools

https://github.com/akexorcist/Android-GoogleDirectionLibrary

Simple syntax

```
GoogleDirection.withServerKey("YOUR_SERVER_API_KEY")
        .from(new LatLng(41.8838111, -87.6657851))
        .and(new LatLng(41.8766061, -87.6556908))
        .and(new LatLng(41.8909056, -87.6467561))
        .to(new LatLng(41.9007082, -87.6488802))
        .transportMode(TransportMode.DRIVING)
        .execute(new DirectionCallback() {
            @Override
            public void onDirectionSuccess(Direction direction, String rawBody) {
                if(direction.isOK()) {
                    // Do something
                } else {
                    // Do something
                }
            }

            @Override
            public void onDirectionFailure(Throwable t) {
                // Do something
            }
        });
```

Answer (score -1):

yes thanx but I'm not realy in search of performance it's just a project for an internship in order to learn kotlin so I don't realy need to boost performance